# Can't seem to get a DataReader to work in C# / SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this code:

```
string strConnect = "Server=DESKTOP-2Q73COU\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=LoginApp;Trusted_Connection=True;";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
conn.Open();

MessageBox.Show("Connected to SSMS.");

string loadMainInfo = "SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE Username = " + Globals.username;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(loadMainInfo, conn);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    lblStanding.Text = (dr["Standing"].ToString());
    lblName.Text = (dr["First Name"].ToString()) + " " + (dr["Last Name"].ToString());
    lblTotalHours.Text = (dr["Total_hours"].ToString());
    lblType.Text = (dr["Degree_type"].ToString());
    lblDegree.Text = (dr["Degree"].ToString());
    lblCurrentHours.Text = (dr["Current_hours"].ToString());
}
```

Specifically this line:

```
string loadMainInfo = "SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE Username = " + Globals.username;
```

If I replace the end of that line with:

```
Username = testuser"
```

The code will work fine and all labels below will be populated with the corresponding info from the tables where Username = testuser. However, if the user logs in with their username and the code is using the original line, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

Any help?

Comment: You should make your life easier and use parameters instead of string concatenation. Not only will it escape and quote things properly for you, il will prevent potential SQL injections.

Comment: Nitpicking: you are *not* connecting to SSMS - this is just a GUI frontend tool. What you're connecting to is **SQL Server** (the database engine)

Comment: Does Little Bobby Tables go to this school?  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

use a SqlParameter to do it as :

```
string loadMainInfo = "SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE Username = @paramName"'; 
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter () ; 
param1.ParameterName="@paramName";
param1.SqlDbType= SqlDbType.Varchar;
param1.Value= Globals.username;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have make a wrong query, add the quote as this

```
string loadMainInfo = "SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE Username = '" + Globals.username + "'";
```

Comment: While this could potentially be the answer to male the code function as expected, it’s very bad practice to use string concatenation for constructing a SQL query.

Comment: use a SqlParameter to do it as : string loadMainInfo = "SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE Username = @paramName"';  
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter ()  ;
param1.ParameterName="@paramName"
param1.SqlDbType= SqlDbType.Varchar;
param1.Value=  Globals.username;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

Comment: You should make that your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.Format

```
string loadMainInfo = String.Format(“SELECT * FROM Main_Information WHERE Username = {0}" ,Globals.username);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Globals.username` may not have a value when you're referencing it for your query string, as the SQL error you're getting occurs when there is nothing following the `=` in the query.

I'd suggest using the debugger to look at the value of `loadMainInfo` just after its been set (or otherwise add the line `MessageBox.Show(loadMainInfo);` below).

Does the query string include the username value you expect?